# How to replace or override the appended html string from a container using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django

There is a container which contains a canvas :

```
<div id="container1">
<canvas id="canvas1" width="378" height="500" > </canvas>
</div>
```

From JS i am appending a html string to this container.

```
$("#Container1").append(html_string1);
```

And it is rendered successfully on the UI.

Now from my views the html string is modified and it calls the js method once again to append the html string to the container but this time it removes the canvas and it doesnot come on UI.

I have tried using methods like:

```
$("#Container1").html(html_string1);
$("#Container1").replaceWith(html_string1);
```

But they all fails. Any help here ?

Comment: Why don't you just do `append` again? What are you trying to do?

Comment: when i append the string again it removes the canvas from the container. I am generating the html string from backend with all the data coming from DB.

Comment: Well, if you use `$("#Container1").html(html_string1);` then of course `canvas` is gone, because you remove the content of `container1` and set it with your `html_string1`. You need to do `$("#Container1").append(html_string1);` again, isn't it?

Comment: A better explanation of expected behavior would help. `all fails` isn't a proper problem description

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/), as you did the first time:

```
$("#Container1").append(html_string1);
```

If you replace the html of the `container1` then you will also replace the canvas, which happens when you do:

```
$("#Container1").html(html_string1);
```

or

```
$("#Container1").replaceWith(html_string1);
```

And if you want to [remove](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) the added html, you would have to do something like:

```
$("#html_string_added").remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to be able to place the html_string in the Container1 and do so multiple times, each time over-writing the previous string. In this case, I would add an element before or after your canvas and add to that.

```
<div id="container1">
<p id="text"></p>
<canvas id="canvas1" width="378" height="500" > </canvas>
</div>

$('#text').html(html_string);
```

It will then be easy to style the contents of html_string without effecting the canvas.